# Replace a char with double qoute

Tags: string, swift

I am constructing json code syntax in a string. The format needs to be {"field":"somedata"} and so on. The problem is that I need to use a string and the code that I wrote is:

```
astring=astring + "{\"field\":\"somedata\"}"
```

The problem is that when I save the string as a textfile the backslashes is also saved and disqualifies this as json.

The I tried to use a diff char (a dog) as a replacement for \" and tried to replace the dog using:

```
res_str=res_str.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("", withString: "\"")
```

But the backslash was included. And finally I tried to

```
res_str=res_str.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("", withString: String(UnicodeScalar(34)))
```

But the backslash is included. In PHP for example I could have used single quote as outer string separator but that isn't allowed in Swift.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think you will be well served by giving this a browse, https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/

Comment: Why do you think that the result contains a backslash? Are you sure that it is not the debugger or the Playground result window which escaped the quotation mark again for the display? Please show your result and how you obtained it. – And yes, of course you should use NSJSONSerialization.